# Is it better to rely on transitive dependencies or explicitly declare them?

Tags: dependency-management

I have a project structure like this:

```
My Project
  - Other Team's Project
     -Third Party Dependency
```

`My Project` requires `Other Team's Project` to function, and both `My Project` and `Other Team's Project` require `Third Party Dependency` to function. We are using a dependency management system to manage these.

From a design perspective, is it better to have `My Project` transitively rely on `Third Party Dependency`? Or is it better for both `My Project` and `Other Team's Project` to both explicitly declare that they use `Third Party Dependency`?

A few other things:

- Both projects need to have the same version of `Third Party Dependency`.
- It is not guaranteed that if `Other Team's Project` is updated that `My Project` will be tested to ensure that nothing breaks, because they are managed by different teams.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Imagine what happens if the other team refactors its project to do the same thing *without* using the third party library and they remove their dependency. Or they switch to another third party library to do the same thing. Will your code still work?

If it does your code only depends on the other project, if not your code depends on the third party library too.

> Both projects need to have the same version of `Third Party Dependency`.

That's a strong indicator that your project directly depends on the third party library too.

Comment: In cases like Python where the application has uses for transitive dependencies it makes sense to declare the dependency outright and let the packaging doing its job to do dependency resolution.  Python and tools like poetry, in particular,  declare  [multiple version support](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#multiple-requirements) and in that way enable clients to determine which version of the now `named` dependency to use.

Answer (score 18):

This is mostly opinion-based I think, but I'll put in my 2p anyway.

The way I've always done it is by asking myself, *what's the minimum amount of knowledge my code **needs** to have to do what its supposed to do?*

If my code only uses code from  `Other team's library`, then I will only include `Other team's library` as a dependency.

If my code *also* uses code from `Third-party library`, then I will include it as well.

Let's say I had the following classes from `My Library`, `Other Library`, and `Third-party Library` (I'll use Java for the example code)

```
package mylibrary;

import otherlibrary.Bar;

public class Foo {

    public void doFoo() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.doBar();
    }
}
```

In the `Other Library`

```
package otherlibrary;

import thirdparty.Baz;

public class Bar {

    public void doBar() {
        Baz baz = new Baz();
        baz.doSomething();
    }
}
```

In the `Third-party library`

```
package thirdparty;

public class Baz {

    public void doBaz() {
        System.out.println("baz");
    }
}
```

Because my code in `Foo` only depends on code from `otherlibrary`, that's all I would include, because that's all I care about. I don't care how `otherlibrary.Bar#doBar` does whatever it does, I just want it to do it.

If however, we changed the `otherlibrary.Bar#doBar` to accept a `Baz` to do something with, like

```
public void doBar(Baz baz) {
    baz.doBaz();
}
```

I would then need to change `mylibrary.Foo#doFoo` to something like

```
public void doFoo() {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Baz baz = new Baz();

    bar.doBar(baz);
}
```

Because I am now interested in how `Bar#doBar` is going to do its thing, and my code **needs** to know about `Baz` to do what I want it to do, I need to be explicit about the libraries I include.

If my code **must** know about stuff within the `thirdparty` library, then I **must** include it as a dependency.

*Although perhaps the author of `Bar` should hide away more of those details so I don't need to include the `thirdparty` library...*

Comment: I'm all for this. But dependency hell is always a problem if, for example, I start with `thirdyparty` version 4 and `otherlibrary` needs version 3. What do you folks do about it?